# What is the difference betweeen specifying "a" and taking whole class/container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

Okay so I've been making website for my mom's business and stumbled onto an interesting thing I can't really find difference on, right now, since website is still in early development.(tried googling but no help)

So basically my question is:

What is the difference in css(and html) between;

`container a:hover;`

and

`container:hover;`

I mean it shouldn't be any different. In both cases, as long as there is only `<a></a>` type used like here, it will apply to everything:

`<a href="index.html">#name of the button</a>`

The thing is here:

```
.nav-link-wrapper:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.nav-link-wrapper a:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Why do I have to specify `a` that is within the class, to apply color, when I don't have to for manipulating borders.

Sry if it was asked. This is more of a beginner's question and I can't find anybody who already asked this.

Comment: `container:hover` will 1. match any `container` that *doesn't* have an `a` tag in it 2. has less specificity than the first selector, so it's easier to override by other CSS rules.

Comment: @VLAZ _"...that doesn't have an `a` tag in it"_ - What? o.O

Comment: There is never one way to achieve the same result. We can do the same thing using different combination of CSS so discussing which one you should use (when both works as intended) is opinion based

Comment: @Andreas missed the "even if" - it will match any `containter` regardless of whether or not it has an `a` tag,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `color` in `.nav-link-wrapper:hover`, it will not affect since `a` tag has its own style. So in order to add style for that `a` tag, you will need to specify `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see why you have to explicitly use a `color` property for your `a` tag is because of the Browser specific color property being applied on it. `color` and `text-decoration` is applied to it explicitly as shown in the image snippet below:-)

And that is true only with `color` property not with any other property. In the code snippet below I am setting `font-size` for the body and it is applied on the `a` tag.

[image]

```css
body{
  color:orange; /*  Parent Not applied */
  font-size:2rem; /* Applied to Child*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="/">Test Link</a>
</body>
```